# VS.NET Tool to name all controls on form

Tags: visual-studio, ide

A while ago, I saw on a Screencast a tool that could be ran in VS.NET IDE.  When executed it would prompt to set the Name and Text property for each control.  This seemed like a good idea, but I never got around to trying it.

Now I can't remember what it is. Does anyone know of a tool that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it [MZ-Tools Control Name Assistant?](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx)

Comment: This looks promising, however I wish there was a freeware version.

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper?](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: I'm looking at this right now, but i don't see that feature available.  Any idea where I should look to get to that feature?